# Mockito ArgumentCaptor capturing multiple times in multithreaded code

Tags: multithreading, mockito

I am trying creating a unit test for my multithreaded code.

My current code snippet is like this:

```
verify(someObject, times(2)).someMethod(captor.capture());
List<SomeObject> list = captor.getAllValues();
assertThat(list.get(0)).isEqualTo(...
assertThat(list.get(1)).isEqualTo(...
```

Now someMethod is called in two separate threads, so the order of captured arguments is nondeterministic. I was wondering if there was a way to assert these arguments without any particular order.

Of course I could write a custom Comparator and sort the list beforehand, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way than this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check that the list contains the elements, independently from the order:

```
assertThat(list, hasItem(...));
assertThat(list, hasItem(...));
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! Exactly what I was looking for.